# Impastata Ricotta for Cannoli

Tags: baking, substitutions, italian-cuisine, pastry

I have been trying to make homemade cannoli filling, but I can not find Impastata Ricotta anywhere. I have tried using regular Ricotta, leaving it to drain in a cheesecloth overnight and then food processes it, and I've also tried with powdered sugar but it is very runny, and very little moisture comes out in the cheesecloth.

Does anyone know:

- How to make Impastata Ricotta?
- Where I can buy it in Phoenix, AZ
- How to treat regular Ricotta so it is similar to impastata? And also which brand to start with.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have the best luck if you separate your question into separate question so they can each get appropriate answers.

Comment: Did you try real ricotta or something else? There is a frightening amount of English speaking sites which have recipes for home-made "ricotta" which are actually paneer-like recipes involving curdling milk with acid. True ricotta is very different, you will have to buy it from a store (and I hope that the producer knows what they are doing).

Comment: I bought several brands from my local grocery store of what is labeled as 'Ricotta cheese'. I don't honestly know if they were 'real' or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use regular Whole Milk Ricotta. Spread the Ricotta out on 1/2 of a white terry towel. Fold the other half of the towel over the cheese. Smooth it out and let it sit, inverting the folded towel after 15-20 minutes to dry the other side. This the best method to dry Ricotta cheese.

Comment: You seem to have posted a new answer rather than editing your existing one. I'll delete the original; if you have further modifications just click "edit" under your answer.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea. I will give this a try next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have had luck befriending employees at local pizza joints, and asking if they will order a bucket for me with their next supply shipment (it pays to tip well).  Many of the companies that pizza shops order from carry ricotta impastata.  It's usually no more than $10 - $20 for a 5lb bucket, and it's perfect for cannoli.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is ricotta impastata.
Don't worry anyway, because in Italy "ricotta impastata" does not exists, so I guess i's a product non intended for the italian market. "Impastata" just means "mixed" so my guess is that it's a regular ricotta just mixed into a sort of cream, and actually I wouldn't sugget you to use such a product.
You can use regular ricotta to make cannoli filling. The best ricotta you can use is made of sheep milk, so you shoud try to find that particular kind of ricotta. If you can't find sheep milk ricotta, you could also use regular cow-milk ricotta.
Once you have the ricotta, it's just a matter of mixing it with the right amount of sugar and optionally other ingredients, such as chocolate drops and so.
Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esU5AcBs9MI) that explains how simple is it.

Comment: I have worked at a Italian bakery in New Jersey and 'impastata ricotta' is what they use. It is much dryer, and as you say smoother... I have not attempted to make my own ricotta, I simply bought a few brands from my local grocery store and put the through the food processor and used my sugar and cinnamon drops, etc recipe from the bakery. But it was super runny. It WAS smooth tho....

Comment: I guess that the error was the food processor. It's a smooth cheese, so you have to be "careful" with it. Just use plain ricotta with sugar and mix them with a wood spoon or something like that.

Comment: "Impastata" might just mean that the ricotta itself is mixed/beaten to smooth out the texture.

Comment: Ricotta Impastata is the finest Ricotta you can use for Cannoli filling. It is only made in Sicily. I am sicilian and my sister uses it for her Cannoli's, They are fantastic!! It is quite expensive but worth the price. Hope this helps for the person that said there is no such ricotta.

Comment: I have tried for ages to make ricotta pie to match the taste and texture of the ricotta pies bought in bakeries. The answer definitely lies in using the IMPASTATA ricotta. There are a couple of famous wonderful bakeries in Boston and New York and they all buy their impastata ricotta from the same place in Connecticut. I am not clear on why several people are caught up in what the name means etc.; the original post was absolutely correct there are no valid options but to get the impastata.

Answer (score 0):

The best ricotta for making cannoli cream is Sorrento whole milk.  It is the preffered cheese of cannoli cream manufactures because it is creamy, dry, and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the storemade cheese again. Use cloth diapers (new) as cheese cloth. Let it set overnight in a strainer with a plate and a heavy jar over the plate. It will take out alot of water.

Comment: Please don't scold askers for asking questions. It is rude. I removed that part from your post.

Answer (score -1):

Impestada is best for making Cannoli Filling.  It is considered the Cadillac of Ricotta Cheese.  This is the only cheese I use to make my cannoli filling.  I buy it at a Specialty Farm Store in my neighborhood, where they sell produce and special cheeses from a local cheese farm.  I have tried regular Ricotta that you buy in a supermarket, but never had good luck with it.  Also, if you are anywhere near an Italian Pastry Shop they might be able to get it for you or maybe even sell you some of it for your recipe.

Comment: Unfortunately here in Arizona the very few Italian pastry shops there is use pre made cannoli filling.... I have searched everywhere with no luck.