# Can I make Ricotta Impastata?

Tags: cheese

Trying to make homemade canollis. Have tried a half dozen different ways, with some success. I recently found an Italian eatery that sells canolli filling in their refrigerated section. This is the exact taste I have been trying to duplicate for months! The first ingredient says “Ricotta Impastatta”...so I think that’s what I need to find. Haven’t found it in any local grocery store or Italian deli. Wondering if I can make this myself somehow since I can’t find it. Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Impastata Ricotta for Cannoli](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42340/impastata-ricotta-for-cannoli)

Comment: @moscafj, I would mark it a duplicate except that the other question *doesn't answer* the question of "what is ricotta impestata".  So I'm going to answer that, and not mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Ricotta Impestata is apparently [ricotta that has been drained and pressed through a fine mesh](https://www.ehow.com/facts_7473249_ricotta-impastata-cheese.html).  So, while you can [order it online](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0716RLFQ4), you can also make it yourself by first draining or blotting the ricotta using paper towels or cheesecloth, and then by pressing it through a tight-mesh strainer.  Personally, I would do the draining but not the pressing, as the latter would be a lot of work and probably not make that much of a difference.

Also, having just made [proper whey ricotta](https://cheesemaking.com/products/ricotta-cheese-making-recipe) not 2 hours ago, I suspect that what the "impestata" process duplicates is the texture of fine whey ricotta, which is quite smooth and creamy compared with whole milk ricotta.  So if you make cheese anyway, try making whey ricotta and draining it thouroughly, and that may give you the texture you're looking for.