# Smooth ricotta texture

Tags: fresh, cheese-making

I once had the opportunity to taste ricotta that was very smooth. The texture was like a thick greek yogurt (but the taste very different). I loved it. I could not find that anywhere else as a consumer. (I am in Andorra, a small country in Europe. I can find Ricotta here but it is not very common and there are not many options)

I try to reproduce that smooth ricotta, without success.

All the ricotta recipes that I have tried do not have that texture. I tried to reincorporate some of the whey at the end and stir. It does not work.

How to make smooth ricotta?

Comment: Have you tried using a food processer or blender?

Comment: @mestackoverflow Good idea, I will try that. First I discarded because I tried with other fresh cheeses and it became too "soupy" and the taste changed. Perhaps I could try carefully as it was whipped cream

Comment: Wow, a very small country indeed!

Comment: I hope you tried real ricotta recipes for homemade ricotta. Sadly, the Internet is full of recipes for congealing whole milk with acid and calling it a ricotta, when it is in fact a different cheese which is an acceptable substitute for some recipes, but doesn't have the actual taste or texture of real ricotta.

Comment: @rumtscho: I am just learning. Can you recommend a good recipe?

Comment: I don't have any special recipe to share, looking around, this is a good summary of the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCfBvXtKPHg. Just search for "ricotta from whey" and you will find written and videotaped recipes of different length and explanation quality. Also, you can use yogurt whey instead of cheese whey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that what you had was indeed ricotta, and not some other smoother cheese (like mascarpone), what you probably had was ricotta forced through a very fine-mesh sieve, as is common for making cannoli, also known as [ricotta impastata](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/96120/can-i-make-ricotta-impastata).  Some cooks also [add a little cream to it to make it even smoother](https://www.washingtonpost.com/recipes/ricotta-cream/15751/).